# javascript function syntax error

Tags: javascript

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
if( numHours >= 8 )
{
return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much";
}
else
{ 
return "Get some more shut eye";
}
};
console.log(sleepCheck(10) );
console.log(sleepCheck(5) );
console.log(sleepCheck(8) );
```

Oops, try again. It looks like sleepCheck() isn't returning "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!" when numHours is 10. Check your if / else syntax and whether you're using the correct comparison operator.

Comment: Could it be as simple as missing the '!'  at the end? Also, welcome to SO. When you ask a question please be sure to actually include, well, a question

Comment: What is the question? What is the syntax error? It seems you only copied some output from some tutorial / exercise. Talk to us!

Comment: The code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

At first I thought you were kind of crazy talking alone at the end of your snipped, then I realized the context. You got stuck in some online tutorial and that text is the output you are being given.

Since tutorials expect an specific output for comparison to decide if you made the job right or not and the `if/else` logic is correct in your snippet, the only thing missing is that your output should match the tutorial's output. Your string is not the same, you are missing a "!" at the end of the first sentence.

Try this:

```
var sleepCheck = function(numHours) {
  if( numHours >= 8 )
  {
    return "You're getting plenty of sleep! Maybe even too much!";
  }
  else
  { 
    return "Get some more shut eye";
  }
};
console.log(sleepCheck(10) );
console.log(sleepCheck(5) );
console.log(sleepCheck(8) );
```

You should be all set :)